# No, it's just right

Tags: grammar

"Is the soup hot?" I asked my son.

> No, it's not hot.
>
> No, it's just right.

My son told me.

How to express the soup temperature is just right, not too hot and not too cold. It's warm.

Comment: I think you just answered your own question: '_No, it's just right._'

Comment: If I say the complete sentence, "The soup is just right." . Would It sound natural to a native speaker.

Comment: "The soup is just right." is perfectly natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either one of those options would work fine, except I would say, “No, it’s not **too** hot” for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

> The soup is just right.

Thanks to G-Cam and Varun KN